# Input disable não é encontrado no serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

Se o form que eu tenho é validado, eu desabilito o form, desta maneira:

```
 $("#Editar :input").prop("disabled", true);
```

Porém eu tenho uma `function` que serialize, e se eu estou com os `forms` desabilitados, eles não encontram o valor. Tem alguma forma de desabilitar os campos, mas que eles ainda sejam encontrados ?

Esta é a função que utilizo, ele compara o form quando é carregado, e o form na hora da ação, e como estão desabilitados, ele não encontra valores.

```
   $(function () {
        var init_form = $('#Editar').serialize(); 
    $(':submit').click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; }); window.onbeforeunload = function () { var check_form = $('#Editar').serialize(); console.log(check_form); console.log(init_form); if (check_form === init_form) return null; return 'Os dados do formulário não foram salvos, deseja permanecer nesta página?'; };
 });
```

No console, o que aparece em branco é o `var check_form = $('#Editar').serialize();` o outro não, como corrigir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade disable realmente não é lida no serialize, tente trocar a propriedade do campo para readonly.

```
$('#inputId').prop('readonly', true);
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado.